# Very high memory usage when profiling python in PyCharm

Tags: python, memory, pycharm, profiling

I'm trying to profile a python application in pycharm, however when the application terminates and the profiler results are displayed Pycharm requires all 16gb of RAM that I have, which makes pycharm unusable.

Said python application is doing reinforcement learning, so it does take a bit of time to run (~10 min or so), however while running it does not require large amounts of RAM.

I'm using the newest version of PyCharm on Ubuntu 16.04 and CProfile is used by Pycharm for profiling.

I'd be very glad if one of you knows a solution.

EDIT: It seems this was an issue within PyCharm, which has since been fixed (as of 2017/11/21)

Comment: I have experienced the same thing with PyCharm once, for a profiling run on my database/integration tests for my own project. I've also experienced a system freeze that required a reboot. The only thing that has seemed to help is to leave PyCharm alone after the profiling finishes, and to only start looking at the results after a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a defect within PyCharm: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-25768